IntelliJ IDEA Kotlin Style - missing Wrapping and Brances -> if() statement -> Force braces option
The following option is present for Java Style but not Kotlin

I'd like to write this:
if (...) { ... } 
else throw IllegalArgumentException("...")

especially because the if and the code inside the brackets is very compact, hence I would like to have an if - if else - else compact structure.
Is there the same option for Kotlin?

Your example shows braces around the if block and no braces around the else block. Is this what you really want? Do you even want the braces at all?

Braces are needed since the if contains two statements.
